# How to run a Yii project developed by someone else?

Tags: php, yii

I am continuing on someone's project developed on Yii. The guy has to transfer the files to me. What I got was a folder with project files and folders (such as protected and public) and a db dump. I am currently testing it on wamp. I have imported the db dump using phpmyadmin, and also updated the db access credentials in `project\protected\config\main.php`.

I have worked a lot on php and its frameworks, but this is my first experience with Yii. I tried to google but every tutorial tells how to create and run a new project and not an existing one.

So can someone please guide me as how can I run this Yii project?

Comment: what is the question? What errors u are getting?

Answer (score -1):

Go through docs first

1. [The official web-site](http://www.yiiframework.com/)
2. [Class Reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/)
3. [Building a blog tutorial. This must answer all your questions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/start.testdrive)